# Entry to Malaysia

Tags: visas, malaysia

My tourist visa issue date was the 18th of March 2019. I am planning to enter Malaysia on the 15th of June 2019 and exit on the 19th of June 2019. Is this ok? Or I will face any problems?

Comment: What are the validity dates on your Visa? How can we tell without those if it is fine?

Comment: @Mahmud According to https://travelvisabookings.com/malaysia-tourist-visa-requirements-and-application-process/ Malaysian tourist visas are usually valid for 3 months from the date of issue.

Comment: There are no validity date mentioned in the visa stamp. Only the date of issue that is 18th March 2019. I just want to know the calculation of 3 months. Is it 90 days or just 3 months like 18th March to 18th April,18th April to 18th May,18th May to 18th June? If i calculate 90 days then dead line of entry to Malaysia is 15th June. Which one i follow? Please Mention the last date i should entry to Malaysia. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears above the center section in the visa. The text reads: "Good for (a single/multiple) journey to Malaysia within (3 months|DATE) from date hereof, provided this passport remains valid".

Answer (score 1):

Malaysia issues multiple types of Tourist Visas.

1. eNTRI - Valid for 90 days.
2. eVisa - Valid for 90 days.
3. Stamped Visa on passport - Usually valid for 1 year, but can be less according to some conditions.

So, if its stamped in the passport then its valid on that date, you won't have any issues. Keep your return ticket, proof of accommodation and proof of funds with you. You can remain in Malaysia for 30 days for the 3rd kind of visa.